# User profile on Data Explorer

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, login

Today I logged in to Data Explorer using my OpenID account, and it didn't fill out automatically my user profile details; or, to be more exact, it filled them in wrongly: it only populated the "login" field, and to do that it took the part before @ of my e-mail address. So, if my address is `somename@somedomain.com`, my account was shown as `somename`.

I was able to edit the fields by hand, but could this be automated using the same process used for the other sites?

Comment: I just logged in for the first time and got the user name john.doe8. Curious!

Comment: Odd Im grabbing Nickname from the sreg fields and falling back to email. Unlike so Im forcing logins to be unique, it makes it easier to keep track of people.

Comment: Doesn't seem to link in to my other stackoverflow accounts either - even if I click the "copy profile to other accounts" button. Doesn't even show up under the accounts tab.

Comment: Is it separate from the SE network somehow?

Comment: @JeffBridgman This related Q (which I just tracked down from the same curiosity!) answers that: [Why doesn't Data Explorer log in with Stack Overflow login?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173257)