# Why doesn't Data Explorer log in with Stack Overflow login?

Tags: feature-request, data-explorer, login

https://data.stackexchange.com/users/10766/jon-doe10767

I logged in with the same Gmail account that I use to log into all my other Stack Overflow accounts and it didn't auto-populate the name. Nor is it showing up here:

https://stackexchange.com/users/276507/neubert?tab=accounts

Seems like it ought to?

Comment: Data.SE is strange overall. Login really shouldn't be needed for 99% of all queries, though.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ehKXa/show

Comment: @asad that's genius. Mind if I steal it?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII Sure; it's already tainted with stealery. The original was by Tim Yi Jiang.

Comment: I just tried it then and I'm apparently "jon.doe10769"

Comment: @Asad updated to get easing from the request place: http://jsfiddle.net/ehKXa/1/show/

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Data.SE never really was part of the SE network. It was made by waffles/Tim Stone as a side project, and  doesn't tie with the rest of the network. I guess that integrating it into the network (associated accounts, etc) would be a very non trivial change, and would require a lot of work for little gain :/

Besides, it's open source. Given that the code for SE is *closed* source, integrating the two so that they both use stackauth may not be possible.

Comment: Waffles? Who the waffle is waffles? ;)

Comment: The open source bit is the key, this means it cannot join our login system cleanly.  Also, it runs from the auxiliary data center, further complicating things.

Comment: I thought [Sam Saffron](http://stackoverflow.com/users/17174/sam-saffron) is creator of Stack Exchange Data Explorer!!!

Comment: @Jeson Sam Saffron===waffles. His meta username used to be "waffles" with a matching logo.

Comment: Interesting.  I had observed the lack of account connection and jumped to the unfounded conclusion that it was a "feature" to preserve anonymity for query activity!