# The added value of adding another login to the account

Tags: discussion, login, user-accounts, linked-accounts

Besides the convenience of the option to click "Sign in with Google" instead of typing login credentials, is there another added value to connect my Google account (for instance) to my StackExchange account?

In addition, will the link with Google only be used to login or also to synchronize details (display name, picture, etc)?

Comment: The picture comes from Gravatar, but you can upload a picture independently of Gravatar.  There's no other added value that I know of, other than Google is a ready provider for the OpenID mechanism that SE uses.

Answer (score 7):

No, no synchronization will happen.

We only use OpenId providers to authenticate you - to make sure that you are who you say you are when you log in.

The benefit of having another OpenId provider is that if one of your providers goes down, you can use another.

Comment: To be fair, if your first OpenID provider has Connect enabled, then the "real name" field of the profile is filled in, I think.

Comment: @Manishearth - I really don't remember. But we essentially don't care, except for authentication.

Comment: @Oded I didn't say **another OpenId provider** but **another login**. The current state is that I have only the regular StackExchange account.

Comment: @Reflection - Another login from the same OpenId provider wouldn't give you anything.

Comment: Oh, sorry, is the StackExchange Account an OpenId provider? However, my question is if there are some benefits of linking to OpenId, besides the convenience, in a situation that I already have a StackExchange Account connected.

Comment: @Oded the OpenID provider may also implement SSO, and thus if the user is logged in to other services from that provider (google and gmail), then one does not need to authenticate again for another request.  Is this correct (and another benefit?)

Comment: "is the StackExchange account an OpenId provider?" - yes, it is. And if the Stack Exchange open Id is offline, you can't log it without an alternative. That's the main benefit.

Comment: @MichaelT - I wouldn't call it another benefit, if one is logged into their OpenId provider already, login tends to happen in the background automatically already.

Comment: @Oded Well that's not always true. [Data.StackExchnage](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173257/148672) doesn't log you in automatically.