# Link registered account in Data Explorer to user profile page

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, user-interface, data-explorer, user-accounts

Lately, I have been consulting and pulling data from Data Explorer Stack Exchange for performing review activities, adding data to meta posts, learn more about some pattern, etc..

I'd like being able to quickly move from my user profile page to my account in SEDE (and move back from there as well).

[image]

Comment: SEDE is not maintained by Stack Exchange but by volunteers. It is open-source. Therefore it cannot be really connected to the proprietary Stack Exchange software.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173257/why-doesnt-data-explorer-log-in-with-stack-overflow-login?r=SearchResults&s=28|17.4154

Comment: also related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/245965/build-stack-exchange-data-explorer-on-top-of-the-stack-exchange-qa-engine?r=SearchResults&s=12|14.8410